# Android EditText.setText OutOfMemoryError when string is very large

Tags: android, android-edittext, out-of-memory

My activity crashes with OutOfMemoryError but I cannot find a way to trap it?

It's a simple activity that is adding a string variable to an edittext.

```
try {
    counter_pat_text.setText(Main.content);
}catch(OutOfMemoryError e){
    Toast.makeText(Edittext.this, "Text file to large!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

As you can see I've tried trapping the error while setting the edittext text but the logcat seems to show the activity failing as it's drawing the layouts?

The string variable "content" is in the calling activity "Main" and when the contents are small I get no errors and the activity and edittext work when opening the 2nd activity with the edittext.

So as I cannot load the activity when the content variable is very very large (932974 characters), how can I trap the OutOfMemoryError? Or how can I calculate what number of characters in the content variable will cause the activity to crash so that I can truncate it in the calling activity?

```
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=26695KB, Allocated=15242KB, Bitmap Size=308KB)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.text.StaticLayout.out(StaticLayout.java:994)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:531)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:261)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:150)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:5266)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:5601)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8553)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1082)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:296)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8553)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(HorizontalScrollView.java:1083)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onMeasure(HorizontalScrollView.java:302)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8553)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3261)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8553)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8553)
09-13 15:56:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(20341):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:873)
```

Comment: Do you think I have not tried google? The first 20 results do not address edittext or how to trap when activity is being drawn!

Comment: The Android UI runs an event loop. Your try-catch fails because the actual exception happens at a later iteration of the event loop. I can tell from the stack trace that it occurs during measurement of the view. You can create a subclass of EditText and in your subclass override the `onMeasure(…)` method. Put the try-catch around the `super.onMeasure(…)` call.

Comment: What is the purpose of displaying that many characters in a EditText?

Comment: It's the result of PDF text extraction. As mentioned: Or how can I calculate what number of characters in the content variable will cause the activity to crash so that I can truncate it in the calling activity?

Comment: That is the wrong question in my opinion. If you put this text into an EditText someone has to read and maybe edit it. So you should ask yourself how many characters are appropriate for that type of element. So you may think about displaying one page only in that EditText.

Answer (score 1):

While you can write code that attempts to catch an Error, there is absolutely no guarantee that it will work.  The Javadoc for the Error class says:

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems
>   that a reasonable application should not try to catch.

By the time the DVM throws an error, it is in serious trouble and may well be in an unrecoverable state.  While you can write code that appears to catch the error:

```
try {
    //...
} catch (Throwable t) {
    // ..
}
```

... it is pretty much whistling in the wind.  The JVM has done its best to tell you that it is too late.

... and come on!  932974 characters???  That's 1M!

Comment: What would be a way of calculating the maximum number of edittext characters that would prevent the error? Then I can can truncate the input.

Comment: I can't see how that is relevant!  The limit is not how many characters will fit in memory, it is how much the user can see.  Why don't you find out how many characters will fit on a reasonable page?

Comment: Edittext is in a scrollview so user could see as far as they were prepared to scroll. I except that the input needs to be truncated to stop the crash but what to truncate it too? Thus the previous comment.

Comment: You want something like google books: a pager.  ... or watch the scroller and add new text at the bottom, as the user scrolls.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Will now be checking size of extracted text prior to saving and if too large to be readable / usable in an EditText will split the file into multiple parts.

Comment: Don't look at me, man.  Folks go around here down-voting stuff if they don't find the question interesting.  Pfft.

Comment: It's probably pretty a pretty safe bet that the people providing useful answers on SO are a different group from the people downvoting questions. Maybe need to raise rep req for downvoting, feels like it's on the upswing.